# Etiqueta HTML, que se puede usar para hacer el recuadro

Tags: html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que etiqueta en `HTML` se puede usar para hacer el recuadro que envuelve a Correos Electrónicos Alternativos

Comment: ¿Te refieres al recuadro grande que engloba todo?¿O sólo al que envuelve los correos electrónicos?

Answer (score 2):

Usa un Fieldset con un Legend

Ejemplo:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Persona:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
</fieldset>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirve mucho

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un `fieldset` para realizar lo que quieres:

```css
*{
  font-family: Arial;
}

textarea{
  height: 80px;
  width: 220px;
}

.add{
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.delete{
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Correos electrónicos alternativos:</legend>
    <textarea>mail1@mail.com   mail2@hotmail.com</textarea>
    <button class="add">Agregar</button>
    <button class="delete">Eliminar</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```